Missing data in OUI_InitialClaims API
OUI_InitialClaims API endpoints does not give data newer than 2016: https://api.dol.gov/V1/Statistics/OUI_InitialClaims/unemploymentInsuranceInitialClaims/?KEY=*******
last event:
<m:properties>
    <d:week m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-12-17T00:00:00</d:week>
    <d:initialClaimsSeasonalFactor m:type="Edm.Decimal">114.6</d:initialClaimsSeasonalFactor>
    <d:continuingClaimsSeasonalFactor m:type="Edm.Decimal">100.3</d:continuingClaimsSeasonalFactor>
    <d:coveredEmployment m:type="Edm.Decimal" m:null="true" />
    <d:nonSeasonallyAdjustedInitialClaims m:type="Edm.Int64">315613</d:nonSeasonallyAdjustedInitialClaims>
    <d:seasonallyAdjustedInitialClaims m:type="Edm.Int32">275000</d:seasonallyAdjustedInitialClaims>
    <d:nonSeasonallyAdjustedContinuingClaims m:type="Edm.Int64" m:null="true" />
    <d:seasonallyAdjustedContinuingClaims m:type="Edm.Int64" m:null="true" />
    <d:seasonallyAdjustedInsuredUnemploymentRate m:type="Edm.Decimal" m:null="true" />
    <d:id m:type="Edm.Int64">1185767</d:id>
</m:properties>```

